# Word for something that is available/accessible all the time

Tags: single-word-requests

I was just wondering if there was a single word to represent the phrase "something that is available/accessible all the time". The context for this is a company that provides services related to information technology.

Comment: "Available 24/7" is one common way to express it. It means 24 hours per day, and seven days per week. Also "round-the-clock". Those expressions tend to differ from one English-speaking country to another.

Comment: All the answers till now are correct for specific uses but this depends on what the something is and what kind of availability/accessibility you are referring to.

Comment: Context for this is a company. Which provides services related to information technology.

Comment: The appropriate word/phrase to use would depend on *what* is available/accessible (personnel, equipment, etc.). Context is key with most things; words and phrases may have very similar dictionary definitions, but only one of a bunch might be appropriate and idiomatic.

Comment: A commodity perhaps?

Comment: Its specific to services. Specially IT services

Comment: **Ubiquitous**:  present, appearing, or found everywhere

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is **[ever-ready](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ever-ready)**.

> Permanently accessible, available, or prepared: *'Roxie’s ever-ready smile'*

---

There is **[handy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Handy)** also which is more common.

> Readily accessible: *found a handy spot for the hammer.*

---

> **Note:** I gave my answers based on the exact definition only. There are different words and phrases that can be used based on the context. If it is related to information technology services, using "available 24/7" would be better.

Answer (score 4):

**at hand** means ready for use. ([dictionary.com - 43c](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/at%20hand))

> We keep a supply of canned goods **at hand**.

Answer (score 4):

It depends a lot on what you are talking about and in which register.

In a formal context I'd try to use **ubiquitous**. It doesn't imply constant availability but constant presence though, and refers more to "everywhere" or "in every situation" than to time itself:

> The internet is almost **ubiquitous** thanks to smartphones.

In other contexts, **available 24/7** (as Spehro suggested) emphasizes time.

Comment: _Ubiquitous_ is more of "is everywhere" than "is available all the time". It still may work for you, depending on what meaning you need.

Comment: -1 Check the dictionary for *ubiquitous*.

Comment: I know its meaning is just "omnipresent". Still, if @Jabir wants to talk about a good or service, it will be understood as "available everywhere", as in "Starbucks is ubiquitous" and "ubiquitous computing".

Answer (score 2):

**on standby**

From [*Merriam-Webster*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20standby):

> **— on standby**
>   :  ready or available for immediate action or use

Comment: _But_, implying that it's **not currently** active (just ready to spring into use).

Answer (score 2):

It is a ***constant***: always there, no matter what.

[Pierceall](http://www.ocregister.com/articles/park-602219-museum-fire.html) in *OrangeCounty Register*, Feb. 24, 2014:

> And as ideas for the park have come and gone, political administrations have changed and a recession had slowed the pace, **Croucher is a constant at events** and city meetings, gently reminding officials that he's still there and still wants to build a museum.

[Leaderhouse](http://www.paherald.sk.ca/Opinion/Columnists/2014-03-03/article-3631515/COLUMN:-Dave-Leaderhouse-%E2%80%94-March-1,-2014/1) in *Prince Albert Daily Herald*, March 03, 2014:

> Everywhere you go (Bob) Marley’s photo is seen and his music is a **constant** at almost every turn.

[Tascon](http://www.tcpalm.com/news/2014/mar/12/helping-imagine-a-world-without-cancer/) in *Vero Beach Newsweekly*, March 12, 2014:

> Davis is a **constant** at many functions with his knack for getting guests to reach into their wallets and purses to help a good cause. He uses serious fundraising techniques and humorous jibes to encourage higher bids.

[emphasis added]

Comment: Although a couple of those sound like American papers, I would say that use of "constant" is rare in the US. I don't recall ever hearing it used in that way. Maybe it's more of a Britishism?

Answer (score 1):

'Ready' has already be posted,  but I'd suggest *at the ready*

> ready for immediate use: “kept guns at the ready” ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ready))

I can also add *uninterrupted*, *perpetual*, *persistent* and other [synonyms for “around the clock”](http://thesaurus.com/browse/around-the-clock).

Answer (score 1):

The marketing buzz term that best fits is "always on" - I went this way since you seem to be looking down the biz buzz path.

Comment: +1 because I didn't see your answer when I posted mine. But, you didn't give an explanation of what always-on means. If you edit to do so, I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Always-on**

This term gets used to describe things like internet connections that are always present without a dial-up, handshake, or log-in process.

The implication is that when you open your browser the internet is there.

So, it definitely describes the IT sense that you mentioned in comments.

An always-on connection.

An always-on resource.

Comment: More complete ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about omnipresent? I'm thinking of Scott Meyer's 'Basic Instructions' comic strip and his superhero Omnipresent-Man! "He's everywhere!"

Answer (score 0):

**Ready and willing** would convey this to me and could be used for an object or a person.

Comment: Single-word? And how could an object be willing?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Why wouldn't an object be willing?  I can add to the other mediocre phrases for this question.  I am always ready and willing.

Comment: A person possesses a will, he or she either chooses or refuses to act in a certain way. I'm not aware of objects capable of the same. Something can be ready, but also willing? I don't think so.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - how do you know objects don't have a will?  I'm saying neutral in case I come back as a hammer.

Answer (score 0):

In the tech world, the phrase is usually ***[high availability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_availability)***. In adjective form, it would be *highly available*, as in

> The cloud computing salesman quoted me $300 per month for a cluster of highly available database machines with 1 TB storage.

This has become (or perhaps always was) more of a marketing term than a technical term. But High Availability is usually backed by a contract, typically called a [Service Level Agreement (SLA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_level_agreement), which contains the exact definition of availability. Without a contract, high availability is just a buzzword (like ["Organic!" or "state of the art"](http://www.adamsherk.com/public-relations/most-overused-press-release-buzzwords/)). The wikipedia page has further details on these concepts.

Answer (score 0):

To summarise the information I've gleaned from the question and subsequent comments:

> - You want to describe something that is always available.
> - It is referring to something IT related.

I'm not sure if it's right for you because we have **very** little information, but here are some suggestions specific to IT.

> - **Mission Critical** component.
>
> > *"Component Z is mission critical, and as such is always online."*
>
> - **Permanently** online/available.
>
> > *"The ISP is able to offer a permanent internet connection."*
>
> - **Uninterruptible** connection (taken from UPS).
>
> > *"Available 24/7, the service is uninterruptible all year round."*

Referring specifically to services in which a person is required could be done with:

> - **On Call**
>
> > *"Our technicians are on call 24/7."*

I realise none of these cater perfectly to the OP's requirements but sometimes the OP doesn't know exactly what they want until they're presented with an option they never explicitly asked for.

Answer (score -3):

'Consistent' can be used. Inconsistent is opposite.

Comment: Hello Prajith K! Welcome to EL&U please take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and read through the [help centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help). Note that answers should provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.